# When verifying that a cryptographic signature was produced by an ethereum address, how can I verify the validity of the data which was signed?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, python, signature, web3.py

I'm attempting to play around with signature verification in solidity through the use of `ecrecover` and have gotten to the point of being able to verify the address which was used to sign a particular message. However, the part where I am getting stuck is verifying the validity of the data that was signed, so that I can ensure that a particular piece of data was signed and submitted, and that another incorrect piece of data which was signed by the same person wasn't submitted instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing the signature scheme, include in the signed data part enough information to uniquely identify what the user is signing.

Comment: Thank you! It just clicked and everything works as expected now :)